# How to define bins in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I've been working with a data set that looks the below data set:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~id,   ~min,    ~max,
  "1",     5,      40,
  "2",     6,      50,
  "3",     7,      70,
  "4",     8,      90,
  "5",    23,     100,
  "6",    18,      40,
  "7",    34,      50,
  "8",    84,     150,
  "9",    15,      70,
  "10",  100,      90,
)
```

Now, I want to plot the histogram by defining the range of bins. I've already plotted the below histogram, and now want to set the range of the bins on the X-axis like this: 0-5, 10-20, 30-50, 50-100.

[image]

Here is my code. Any suggestion?

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(data$min)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), 
                 col = "black", 
                 fill = "red", 
                 alpha = .2) + 
  labs(x = "Min", y = "Count")
```

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829256/how-can-i-control-bin-intervals-in-ggplot2) should be of some use.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess not actually, the bin is 20 wide in this example.

Comment: You can change the breaks intervals. `breaks = seq(....)` is a vector of values, as eastclintw00d has demonstrated. I'm not sure how to exlude certain intervals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i control bin intervals in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829256/how-can-i-control-bin-intervals-in-ggplot2)

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess thanks for finding the duplicate question, I have flagged this now - you can always flag questions as duplicate so it gets our attention and we can close vote it.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust `breaks` to your needs:

```r
ggplot(data=data, aes(data$min)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 20 , 30, 50, 100), 
                 col = "black", 
                 fill = "red", 
                 alpha = .2,
                 ) + 
  labs(x = "Min", y = "Count")
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to peg the size of the ticks on the x-axis even they don't have the same range?

Comment: I think that should work (from @Joe):

output <- cut(data$min, breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 20 , 30, 50, 100)) 

table(output) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = output, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_col()

Comment: Good find on the output above.